# Mirroring PointCloud data as laserScan data

Tags: ros, rviz, 2dlaserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Using the depthimage_to_laserscan package, I can convert pointcloud data from the depth camera into laser data and display them in the rviz environment. In the same way, I can create a costmap. But pointcloud data doesn't show obstacles higher than the robot's own size as a costmap. Like lidar data, it only takes into account its own axes. And when that happens, my robot crashes into that object. Is there a way to set this in the package I'm using? I want it to take the minimum value from the Z axis and return it and reflect it as laser data. Or do I have to write code myself? Thank you.

ROS: Noetic
System: Ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414098/mirroring-pointcloud-data-as-laserscan-data/) by [furkan_](https://answers.ros.org/users/144606/furkan_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `depthimage_to_laserscan` node does not know your robot's height. The doc says it reads a single pixel row of the rectangular depth image (the middle row in the y-dimension.) But you can configure the node to read additional rows from the depth image.

http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan#Parameters

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [furkan_](https://answers.ros.org/users/144606/furkan_/) on 2023-04-10**:
Thank you. I was able to solve the problem with the "scan_height" parameter. But the smallest points from the camera also appear as costmaps. Do you have any suggestions on this subject?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-04-11**:
Only the obvious: write a filter to remove points from the pointcloud. I have no suggestion for an existing filter to do this for you.

**Comment by [furkan_](https://answers.ros.org/users/144606/furkan_/) on 2023-04-11**:
Thank you.